# Which one of these two code samples are supposed to be faster?

Tags: java, performance, primes

I was scrolling through edabit doing some of their challenges when I stumbled across one where you were to return the amount of prime numbers under the passed value. I completed the challenge and wanted to check if my solution was quicker than most others, so I checked one and found out that my code, according to the program at least, was slower even though mine is supposed to do fewer checks.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public static int test1(int num) {
    int primes = 0;
    for(int i = 3; i<=num; i+=2) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for(int j =  (int) Math.sqrt(i); j>1; j--) {
            if(i%j==0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(prime == true) primes++;
    }
    return (num >= 2 ? primes+1 : 0);
}
```

and here is the other one:

```
public static int test2(int num) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            if (i % j == 0){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 2){
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

By a quick look over you can see that mine is almost the same as the other code sample but optimized as it is supposed to do fewer checks as the number of times it will loop is less. However, that is apparently not the case. Could someone please tell me why my code would not be running as fast or faster than the other code sample? I only tested values between 1 and 150 in case that information is useful.

Comment: Both of them have problems: e.g. both of them are supposed to break when `i % j == 0`. In the second one, you only have to check up to `sqrt (i)` i.e. `j <= i` should be better written as `j<=Math.sqrt(i)`.

Comment: I agree with my homeboy Arvind, but a) it's impossible to evaluate a 3rd party platform's ranking system and b) this question isn't very suitable for SO in any case (maybe code review, but... I have my doubts).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash No, that would just break the code? I mean if I break it wouldn't allow for it to keep checking for values that are divisible.

Comment: @YayL - You should break the inner loop as soon as you find that the number, `i` is divisible by `j`. Isn't it? Isn't one divisibility enough to say that the number is not prime?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Ohh I get what you mean now, I understand now. Sorry

Comment: @YayL - No worries. You can check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test for my suggestion of using `sqrt(i)` as the terminating condition in the inner loop.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash No, yeah I understand the reason behind it and was thinking about it being what you're supposed to check up to. However, even after implementing both of these optimizations, my code runs slower than the other one for some unknown reason.

Comment: @YayL - The main problem with your code (the latest update) is that you are starting from the upper-end while in most cases, the factors are located nearest to `1` i.e. you should use `for(int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++)`